# Which one of "holding" and "carrying" is more appropriate here?

Tags: word-choice

> A figure **holding/carrying** a sword stepped out of the mist.

If the man or what he is, is holding the sword with one hand, which one is more appropriate here?

Comment: Both are correct and equally likely to be used in this context.

Answer (score 1):

"Carrying" has a slight connotation of passivity - it might mean that the sword is in its scabbard, or supported by both arms.

"Holding", however strictly means that the sword is in the hand of the person, and suggests that the sword is 'ready for use', so is a slightly more aggressive description.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of writing, put passed the idea of doing so!

Comment: @MikeBrockington I am not quite sure that I agree about the difference in connotation between “holding” and “carrying” a sword. The normal verb to denote having a sword in a scabbard is “wearing a sword.” I am certainly not going to downvote a solid answer over this minor point on which I am not even sure that I am right. In fact, I am upvoting.